# SQL query for max time with group on string excluding groups with null time rows

Tags: sql, null, group-by, max

I know there are a lot of questions regarding using max with a group by <strike>but I promise this one is trickier.</strike> *(ok...so it was so easy it was answered in 10 minutes)*

Here's a sample table

```
|ID|name|     end_time     |
|01|Bob |2012-02-09 3:00:00|
|02|Bob |2012-02-09 3:15:00|
|03|Ted |2012-02-09 3:00:00|
|04|Ted |null              |
```

What I want is to return the max time grouped by name but exclude names that have a null end_time.

I started with

```
SELECT * FROM table t,(
   SELECT MAX(end_time), name FROM table
   GROUP BY name
) last_entry
WHERE t.name = last_entry.name
  AND t.end_time = last_entry.end_time
```

The problem is that this gives me ID 02 and 03 whereas I want it to return only 02.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understood your question correctly, you can solve it by excluding names with null end times in any other row:

```
SELECT MAX(end_time), name
FROM table t
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM table tt
    WHERE end_time is null AND tt.name=t.name
)
GROUP BY name
```

Comment: Spot on. And now that I see it it's obvious.  Guess I'll have to retract my statement that this was at all tricky.  Thanks a million.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one, you don't need name in group in finding max date.

```
SELECT * FROM table t,(
       SELECT MAX(end_time) FROM table
    ) last_entry
    WHERE t.end_time = last_entry.end_time
```

Comment: That's ignoring the fact that only one date per name is desired AND that only names with no null dates be considered.